# quickblox for web - create 1 to 1 chat

Tags: quickblox

I am trying to create 1 to 1 chat from a web client.

I downloaded the SDK and the group chat example.
There seem to be really good examples for all platforms except the web.

(for example: http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample)

Can anyone provide code/example/directions?

Am i missing something or is the documentation for the web is really lacking?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone? Where can i find directions how to use the web SDK to create one to one chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebSDK is enough new. And we work on its documentation.
But,here, I will show you some code snippets how you can create one to one chat.

As you know QuickBlox uses XMPP-server as a Chat service.
WebSDK doesn't have a wrapper around XMPP API, so you should include additional XMPP JS library.

For our examples, we recommended to use Strophe.js (http://strophe.im/strophejs/)

Let's begin:

1) Include your xmpp js library and WebSDK

```
<script src="quickblox.js"></script>
<script src="strophe.js"></script>
```

2) Describe your QB credentials

```
var QBAPP = {
  app_id: '<your QuickBlox id>',
  auth_key: '<your QuickBlox key>',
  auth_secret: '<your QuickBlox secret>'
};

// our parameters to connect to QuickBlox Chat service
var CHAT = {
  server: 'chat.quickblox.com',
  bosh_server: 'http://chat.quickblox.com:5280'
};
```

3) Create QB session with user authentication

```
var params, connection;
params = {
  login: '<your QB login>',
  password: '<your QB password>'
};

QB.init(QBAPP.app_id, QBAPP.auth_key, QBAPP.auth_secret);
QB.createSession(params, function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.detail);
  } else {
    connectChat(res.user_id, params.password);
  }
});
```

4) Connect to QuickBlox Chat server with your user JID and password (http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Connecting_to_server)

```
function connectChat(user_id, password) {
  var userJID = user_id + "-" + QBAPP.app_id + "@" + CHAT.server;
  var userPass = password;

  connection = new Strophe.Connection(CHAT.bosh_server);
  connection.rawInput = rawInput;
  connection.rawOutput = rawOutput;

  connection.connect(userJID, userPass, function (status) {
    switch (status) {
    case Strophe.Status.ERROR:
      console.log('[Connection] Error');
      break;
    case Strophe.Status.CONNECTING:
      console.log('[Connection] Connecting');
      break;
    case Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL:
      console.log('[Connection] Failed to connect');
      break;
    case Strophe.Status.AUTHENTICATING:
      console.log('[Connection] Authenticating');
      break;
    case Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL:
      console.log('[Connection] Unauthorized');
      break;
    case Strophe.Status.CONNECTED:
      console.log('[Connection] Connected');

      // Create an event handler for getting messages
      connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', null, null, null);
      // send a presence message
      connection.send($pres().tree());

      break;
    case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING:
      console.log('[Connection] Disconnecting');
      break;
    case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED:
      console.log('[Connection] Disconnected');
      break;
    case Strophe.Status.ATTACHED:
      console.log('[Connection] Attached');
      break;
    }
  });
}

// logs
function rawInput(data) {console.log('RECV: ' + data);}
function rawOutput(data) {console.log('SENT: ' + data);}
```

5) Function for receive messages

```
function onMessage(msg) {
  console.log(msg);

  var to = msg.getAttribute('to');
  var from = msg.getAttribute('from');
  var type = msg.getAttribute('type');
  var elems = msg.getElementsByTagName('body');

  // we must return true to keep the handler alive.  
  // returning false would remove it after it finishes.
  return true;
}
```

6) Function for send messages

```
function sendMessage() {
  params = {
    to: '<some JID>', // JID of recipient QB User
    from: connection.jid, // JID of sender QB user
    type: 'chat' // type of the message
  }
  var msg = $msg(params).c('body').t('Hello world!');
  connection.send(msg.tree());
}
```

I'm sure, that it helps you to create one to one chat with QuickBlox using Javascript.
If you want to use the group chat, you can look at 'Chat module code' from develop branch of Web XMPP chat sample:
https://github.com/QuickBlox/sample-chat-xmpp-web/blob/develop/qbchatroom.js

Today we finished new sample's design https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0qNZ.png and very soon will deploy that to production.

Comment: Hey

Thanks a lot!

I still got one problem though. 
Let me start by saying (a side note) that i think the code you posted needs a small change: the variable 'connection' is not defined inside  the function sendMessage.
Anyway, the problem i'm facing now is:  
when  connection.send(msg.tree())  is called i get: 

POST http://chat.quickblox.com:5280/ 405 (Invalid hostname.) 

Don't know if it is a proxy issue, a problem with the URL or something in the clinet. (though my code is 98% identical to the one you published)

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show me `console.log(params)` from the function sendMessage?

Comment: sure. currently try to send and receive by same user:

Comment: Object {to: "767579-5339@chat.quickblox.com", from: "767579-5339@chat.quickblox.com", type: "chat"}

Comment: the problem is only with post. If i comment out the line: connection.send(msg.tree()); i get no errors.

Comment: Thanks for note with variable 'connection'. I put it in place outside the function. But you said me (though my code is 98% identical to the one you published). And what about the remaining 2%? :) Because I checked this code and it works. Please tell me what did you change?

Comment: Hi, I tried your example, but I am getting an error. The POST request to http://chat.quickblox.com:5280/ fails. Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi Durty, what http-code and the error are in response from server?

Comment: Hi , "the remaining 2%": 1. I defined the 'connection' variable at the top level and passed it as a parameter to the functions 'connectChat' and 'sendMessage'. 2. inside 'sendMessage' i initialized the 'to','from' variables as i posted a few comments above [ the console.log(params) ]. 3.inside the functions 'QB.createSession' after the line 'connectChat(res.user_id, params.password); ' i make a call to 'sendMessage'. That's all.

Comment: If there is more info i can provide to diagnose the problem i'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: if further analysis i see that one connection to the server is successful - <body rid='2051786350' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='55394793-a5b0-45e3-9946-4c30ddaa10b0'/> and the other one fails: <body rid='2051786349' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message to='767579-5339@chat.quickblox.com' from='767579-5339@chat.quickblox.com' type='chat' xmlns='jabber:client'><body>Hello world!</body></message></body>. Maybe this info will be helpful. (what i pasted above seems to be the difference between the successful and unsuccessful requests)

Comment: Does that mean that any QB user can message each other if they know the app id + username combination?

Comment: Only if these users belong to a single QuickBlox application

Comment: @WebDev, Hi, could you please provide any link where I can learn to implement one  to one video chat using quickblox. I have been trying to implement quickblox-javascript-sdk-master/samples/webrtc/, it works on same system with different browsers, but when I try to use the same on different systems, it does not. How can I make it work on different systems connected by LAN. I know I am missing something, but do not know exactly what. Please let me know, if you know any tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you might see the 405 error because you have put the call of sendMessage function immediately after the call of connectChat function.

To connect to the chat needs some time, so you can not send the message until your client (browser) hasn't finished the connecting to the chat server at first. You need to put the call of sendMessage function in callback from function connectChat where a status is "Connected". Or you can perform sendMessage function on an onclick event to the tag `<button>` or something else. For your example, insert sendMessage like here:

```
case Strophe.Status.CONNECTED:
    console.log('[Connection] Connected');

    connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', null, null, null);
    connection.send($pres().tree());

    sendMessage();

    break;
```

Comment: problem solved by calling ' sendMessage();' from within 'connectChat' Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from today QuickBlox has a own Web XMPP Chat plugin for WebSDK.
You can look here the new example for 1:1 Chat which uses this library:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample