# How to use 1:1 chat using QuickBlox sample chat example in android

Tags: android, eclipse, quickblox

I have performed all the necessary tasks to work with 1:1 chat using QuickBlox SDK as mention in site : http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

In my Emulator when i select a user from a list of users and give other user's(the user who want to communicate to the first user) username and password. It opens a simple chat platform with single user

It opens in my Android ICS tablet and displays User when i select a user and use another user's(the user who want to communicate to the first user) username and password the stops giving message Unfortunately QuickBlox Sample Chat was stopped.

I have also referred to the post: [quickblox for web - create 1 to 1 chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114829/quickblox-for-web-create-1-to-1-chat/21377863#21377863?newreg=65f23187313a4a05aad9b2650527ced5)
but I didn't know where to put those data and how to include the XMPP JS library.

I am a beginner to Android programming and also using QuickBlox SDK.
Please help me to solve the problems.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please, provide code and log, so we could help you.

Comment: Sir, I did the only change in this code as instructed : private static final String APP_ID = "7445";
    private static final String AUTH_KEY = "EYHPbRgLrwUq8HN";
    private static final String AUTH_SECRET = "wAC9Y-HnYBJ6SJt";

Comment: rest of the code is as same as the Sample code. I didn't do any customization.