# Quickblox - create 1 to 1 chat web application

Tags: quickblox

I want to create a very basic one to one web chat application using Javascript SDK.

I followed the following link: http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample and also saw post 
[quickblox for web - create 1 to 1 chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114829/quickblox-for-web-create-1-to-1-chat)

But i cannot make an application where two added users are able to chat. What i have done so far:
1. Downloaded javascript SDK.
2. Created my own Chat App as instructed and added two users to that application in dashboard.
3. Copied QBApp, QBUser1, QBUser2 credentials to the config.js inside the Samples> Chat> JS folder.

The config.js now looks like:

```
var QBApp = {
  appId: 28143,
  authKey: 'KVCCFAQXGsNRq22',
  authSecret: 'VNkQ5frbgexXeqH'
};

var config = {
  chatProtocol: {
    active: 2,
  },
  debug: false
};

var QBUser1 = {
      id: 5352004,
      name: 'user1',
      login: 'chatUser1',
      pass: 'password'
    },
    QBUser2 = {
      id: 5352010,
      name: 'user1',
      login: 'chatUser2',
      pass: 'password'
    };
```

I cannot establish communication with this. I think i have done something wrong in config.js entries?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you receive any errors? or what?

Comment: http://s9.postimg.org/52pzs1y2n/Console_Error.png

This is the snapshot of the console error i am getting. The first one comes on page load and the second one comes when i click on Create Dialog button.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/fd9gbmhr1/
http://s7.postimg.org/u5qj49mqj/Chat_Appln_Users.png

This is application, user details snapshot. In the original post i had copied the original contents on config.js. Can you please tell me where i am doing wrong?